How to attach url params to webpack dev server host?
I use webpack dev-server with npm and having simple config file all works perfectly except that I would like to have dev-server runnning the browser with additional url params attached to 'host' url.
config:
...
{
            static: path.resolve(__dirname, "../public"),
            host: "localhost",
            hot: true,
            port: 8080
}
...
target: "web"

Unfortunately adding anything to host like:
"localhost/?developer=John"

will not work, but I would like to set this param in config.js (which is handled then in the code) than copy paste it to url every time dev sever runs.
Is there anyway to attach url params to the host url running the code with webpack dev server ?
Thanks in advance

Could you please try to add the given line
publicPath: "http://localhost/?developer=John",
after port : 8080.
When we setting up publicPath to "http://localhost/?developer=John", the webpack dev server will start serving your application files from this URL.

I am using webpack & dev-server with version 5.x and I think there is no such a parameter - "publicPath".
CLI output in this case:
[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

options has an unknown property 'publicPath'. These properties are valid:
object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, ipc?, liveReload?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer?


Looking into webpack docs I found that "publicPath" parameter applies into "output" object in configuration. Unfortunately by adding it I retrieve "failed: connection refused" as the script code in my index.html executes request to external server with something like that:
http://localhost/?developer=John/https://external-server.com/data/anything.js
